# Questions about a trick for solving quadratic equations quickly

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, quadratics, factoring

I just watched a video that teaches a trick to solve some quadratic equations faster:

> Suppose we have $3x^2-152x+100=0$ It takes a lot of time to solve it
> by finding discriminant because we have to calculate
> $152^2$ and so on. we divide $3x^2$ by $3$ and multiply $100$ by $3$
> and we get: $x^2-152x+300=0$ we can solve it easily by factoring
> $(x-150)(x-2)=0$ then we divide the roots by $3$ so the roots of
> original quadratic are $\frac{150}3$ and $\frac23$

It is the first time I see this trick. so is it a known method?

And How we can prove this method works mathematically?

Comment: $a$ only appears in $4ac$ in the formula for quadratic solution and when you divide by it $4*a/3*3c=4ac$.

Comment: @MartinR I just checked for $\frac23$ in my head but not $50$.

Comment: Well you could as well factor it as $(3x-2)(x-50)$. I don't much difference in the "easiness" of factorization between $x^2-152x+300$ and $3x^2-152x+100$.

Comment: The trick trades $ax^2+bx+c=0$ for $x^2+bx+ac=0$, whose roots are $a$-times those of the original. The advantage for factoring is that you don't have to worry about pairing factors of the $x^2$ term w/factors of the constant term; you can just focus on the constant. The trade-off is that you've increased the ways the constant factors, so there are just as many options to check. I'd probably stick w/the original method, where the numbers are smaller, but options are good. Of course, *most* quadratics don't factor over integers, so it might be best to get familiar w/the Quadratic Formula.

Comment: @zwim I showed this in my answer.

Comment: @amirali: I am able to factor monic polynomials mentally. Not otherwise.

Comment: After all I think it is useful to use this trick consciously (not with memorizing the method without knowing the reason).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nice trick, I never saw it.

$$ax^2+bx+c=0\iff a^2x^2+abx+ac=0\iff (ax)^2+b(ax)+ac=0.$$

So you solve for $ax$ and divide by $a$.

---

You can combine with another trick that I like, when $b$ is even or a factor $2$ can be pulled out (this is a frequent situation):

$$x^2+2bx+c=0\iff x=-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-c}.$$

Comment: Long time I did not see the $2b$ !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: haha !  I use it twice a day :-)

Comment: Me too : it is so convenient. Coupled with the trick (I did not know),  it is nice. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, your method can be proved to be correct.

Consider the quadratic - $ax^{2} +bx+c=0$ where $a$ is assumed to be non-zero. It's roots are given by the quadratic formula-
\begin{equation*}
\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^{2} -4ac}}{2a}
\end{equation*}
And by your method, the quadratic changes to $x^{2}+bx+ac=0$.
It's roots are -
\begin{equation*}
\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^{2} -4ac}}{2}
\end{equation*}
You propose to divide the roots by $a$, so that just means they are the roots of the original equation.

Nice trick, but is it really feasible?

Comment: You just proved that it's feasible :)

Comment: @Righter No I mean, is it necessary to do the extra calculation when the quadratic formula can be used just as well?

Comment: Well, one can factorise it either way, but it's easier to do it instinctively when $a=1$ (I don't think anyone's going to do it by quadratic formula without a calculator in hand)

Comment: @IshraaqParvez: what extra computation ?

Comment: @Righter Yes, you do make a good point. The first way I learned to solve quadratic equations was by factorisation, and it is still the method I use most of the time.

Comment: @YvesDaoust The multiplication, but another user mentioned a very good point.

Answer (score 1):

I have known a cousin of this trick for long, not sure of where from though.  Essentially like in factoring method, you multiply $3\times100$ and split the product $300$ into two so that the sum is $-152$, like so
$$3x^2-150x - 2x +100 = 3x(x-50)-2(x-50)=(3x-2)(x-50)$$

---

In general the logic here is that $$(px+q)(rx+s) = prx^2+(ps+qr)x+qs$$
so if there is a nice factoring of the quadratic, the middle term coefficient should be a sum of two whose product is $pqrs$.  One then considers the possible ways to split it back.

Answer (score 1):

This trick is correct. But, unfortunately I cannot call it "nice".
I will try to show you the reason for this.

---

First alternatively, you can easily prove this  trick using Vieta's formula.

$$ax^2+bx+c=0$$

$$x_1+x_2=-\frac ba, ~ x_1x_2=\frac ca$$

Then,

$$y^2+by+ac=0$$

$$y_1+y_2=-b, ~ y_1y_2=ac$$

Putting $$x_1=\frac {y_1}{a},~ x_2=\frac{y_2}{a}$$

You get,

$$x_1+x_2=-\frac ba, ~ x_1x_2=\frac ca$$

which is correct.

---

I did not find this trick useful specifically for this equation for the following reason:

#### Observation

The implementation of this trick is based on the following observation:

$$150+2=152, ~ 150\times 2=300.$$

Isn't it?

But, this trick already works in the original equation:

$$\begin{align}3x^2-152x+100=0\end{align}$$

$$\iff 3x^2-150x-2x+100=0.$$

It is likewise easy to observe:

$$\frac{150}{3}=50, ~ \frac{100}{2}=50$$

This fact is equivalent to observe that

$$150+2=152, ~ 150\times 2=300.$$

Finally we have,

$$\begin{align}3x^2-152x+100=0
&\iff 3x^2-150x-2x+100 \\
&\iff 3x(x-50)-2(x-50) \\
&\iff (3x-2)(x-50).\end{align}$$

Which one is easy?  Make up your own mind.

---

Also, don't forget about the "half-discriminant" method.

If $$ax^2+2kx+c=0, a≠0$$ then

$$x_{1,2}=\dfrac{-k±\sqrt{k^2-ac}}{a}.$$

Comment: Direct application of Vieta requires two divisions. You are lucky if they give integer results. If not, the sum/product decomposition can be painful. The OP's technique only takes a multiply and stays in the integers.

Answer (score 0):

Let the original equation be $ax^2+bx+c=0$.

Let us divide degree $2$ term by $a$ and multiply constant term by $a$.
Then we get $x^2+bx+ac=0$.

The roots of this are $$x={{-b±\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}\over 2}$$
Dividing the roots by $a$, we get $${x\over a}={{-b±\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}\over 2a}$$
which are the roots of the original equation. Hence proved.